# Sightly expression to compare string property with list count

Tags: aem, sightly

I am trying to compare two values, one coming from dialog and other is count var of Map. But getting an error:

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Invalid types in comparison. Comparison is supported for Number types only

This is simple code of getting the List of links of pages, but if max count set will show restricted(max) no. of links. If three set as max count only 3 links will come in list.

```
<div id="${properties.containerId}" class="${properties.containerClass}">
<div data-sly-use.listOfLink="com.aem.web.core.components.ListOfLink" data-sly-unwrap>

    <div data-sly-list.keyName="${listOfLink.pageMap}" data-sly-unwrap>
        <div data-sly-test.maxcount="${properties.maxcount}" data-sly-unwrap>
        <!-- Check the max count set in dialog(property ) for link to display from Map-->
            <div data-sly-test="${keyName.count <= properties.maxcount}"  data-sly-unwrap>
                <p><a href="${keyName}">${listOfLink.pageMap[keyName][0]</a></p>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the object holding the variables is the list and not the listed item. In the link it shows an example...

http://docs.adobe.com/docs/br/aem/6-0/develop/sightly.html#list

```
<div data-sly-test="${keyNameList.count <= properties.maxcount}" data-sly-unwrap>
```

Answer (score 1):

For following comparison operators: `< <= >= >`, Sightly requires numeric types. But it doesn't matter where the variables come from, and it works as expected whether they come from a property or from the list counter (or a mix of both). It is likely that in the content repository, your value has been stored as text (String) and not as a number (Decimal, Double, or Long). Either tweak your dialog to use a Number Field, in order to store the value as a number in the repository, or, as andeh suggested, make the conversion in the Use-API.

Then, as Christopher noted, the object holding the `count` variable of your list ist `itemList`, or as your renamed the `item` variable, it is `keyNameList` in your case.

Additionally, note that the goal of Sightly is to **reuse** the HTML elements for the template logic, in order to not clutter the markup with template blocks. But adding each Sightly instruction on a separate `<div>` element, and then removing them again with `data-sly-unwrap` really should be avoided! It makes the markup very hard to read, as one doesn't know anymore which `<div>` will get displayed and which one is only for logic.

So your template could be written as follows, without any `data-sly-unwrap`:

```
<div id="${properties.containerId}"
     class="${properties.containerClass}"
     data-sly-use.listOfLink="com.aem.web.core.components.ListOfLink"
     data-sly-list.keyName="${listOfLink.pageMap}">
    <p data-sly-test="${properties.maxcount && keyNameList.count <= properties.maxcount}">
        <a href="${keyName}">${listOfLink.pageMap[keyName][0]}</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

And if you cannot change the dialog to store numbers, in the Use-API you can force your string property to be a number. The following code illustrates that the ListOfLink object extends WCMUsePojo:

```
public int getMaxcount() {
    return getProperties().get("maxcount", 0);
}
```

Which you can then access in your template as `${listOfLink.maxcount}`.

Also useful might be the following [Sightly Style Guide from Netcentric](http://www.netcentric.biz/blog/2015/08/aem-sightly-style-guide.html).

Answer (score 0):

Sling inject maxcount into your java class. Create a getter, and retrieve it in sightly with `listOfLink.maxcount`.

```
<div data-sly-test="${keyName.count <= listOfLink.maxcount}"  data-sly-unwrap>
            <p><a href="${keyName}">${listOfLink.pageMap[keyName][0]</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I know it can achieve it through Java, but is there a way we can achieve this simple operation without java?